# ImageMagick count how many identical or almost identical color pixels are vertically by x coordinate

Tags: imagemagick

I have this image:

[image]

I need to count how many red pixels there are vertically on `x 60` which would be the red line on the right containing 4 pixels.

I tried this:

```
img.png -alpha off -fuzz 2% -fill white -opaque "#FF0000" -fill black +opaque white -gravity west -crop 61x+0+0 -format "%[fx:round(mean*w*h)]\n" info:
```

but it also counts all the red pixels left to `x 60`

Comment: Try `-crop 1x+61+0` to crop a full-height, 1px wide column starting at 61,0.

Comment: Yep works.. thanks! Please post it as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
magick ... -crop 1x+61+0 ...
```

to crop a full-height, 1px wide column starting at 61,0.